# ActiveAndroid clean DB

Tags: android, mysql, database, activeandroid

My Android Application is using ActiveAndroid, the DB tool.
The database is only a short local cache. All the data is repeatedly updated from the server.
It works well. I can drop tables and refill-them easily.

```
Delete().from(ObjectA.class).execute();
for ...
    objectA.save();
```

For special cases I now wanted to provide a setting, where you could drop the whole DB. All Tables and the db schema.
Something similar to a db-version update. How to do this?

So fare I just found this

```
activity.deleteDatabase(dbName);
```

which works, and does exactly what I want. But then I've got the issue, that db-access is broken until the next app-restart. Is there no way to re-initialize Active-Android without App-restart?

Answer (score 0):

As I know you can get it using just this:

```
new Delete().from(ObjectA.class).execute();
```

If it don't work try this:

```
public static List<Items> getAll() {
    return new Select().from(Items.class).execute();
}

...

mItems = Items.getAll()
for(Items item : mItems) {
    item.delete();
}
```